# MySQL Server PID Error on Start

Tags: mysql, sql, macos

Currently running `Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5` and `MySQL 5.6.25`.

MySQL starts fine at home, but not at my University.

I tried port scanning range `3306` and couldn't find any port open. I'm assuming they blocked it.

Is this likely the source of the error?

`Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file`

What is the best course of action from here? Looking into tunnelling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to `chmod -R 777` on my `/usr/local/mysql-5*/` directory.

Comment: This is ridiculous, don't do that.

Comment: Yikes. Why is this bad? It's only localhost. Can I recover from this mistake? And why would it make MySQL work when I am university?